# Is it possible to use CA signed keys to SSH from Windows to Linux with putty?

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, putty, certificate

A number of Linux servers have been set up so that they have `TrustedUserCAKeys` in their sshd_config.

My public SSH key is not and should not be installed on any of these servers. Instead, when I need access to any of these services, I get a piece of software to sign my public SSH key with the CA certificate that the servers trust as above. The issued signature is short-timed so it's valid, say, for half an hour.

Say, my private key is stored in `mykey` file and my public key is stored in `mykey.pub` file. So said piece of software authenticates me and, when it's satisfied that I have the necessary access, issues me with a signature of my `mykey.pub`, which I then store in `mykey-cert.pub` file. With all three files in the current directory I issue this command on Linux:

```
ssh -i mykey myname@server
```

and I'm in.

I would like to be able to access these Linux servers from Windows too. I of course could try and use cygwin or msys ssh, but I like the convenience of PuTTY.

Is there any way for me to make PuTTY understand and communicate my CA signed key to the servers?

Comment: Looks like putty [does not support it](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh2-openssh-certkeys.html). Bummer!

Comment: Looks like you found your own answer. Please post it as a proper Answer (rather than just a comment), and then accept your own Answer by clicking the checkmark next to your Answer. That way SuperUser will show that this question has been resolved.

Comment: @Spiff it's a good practice to keep questions open for a few days to give others a chance to contribute.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh You clearly have an answer.  You should submit an answer today.  A few days won't change the fact you have an answer.  If somebody submits a better answer you can always change your accepted answer.  Putty doesn't support it, that won't change in a few days, that will never change until the software is updated.

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm always surprised to ingenuity of our excellent community, who can come up with unexpected and brilliant answers when you least expect that. You could be surprised. But even if not - no harm done.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact you should still submit your answer

Comment: @Ramhound I totally intend to.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh When do you think you'll do that?

Comment: @SimonJGreen thank you for reminding me, I accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenSSH certificates are not implemented in anything else than OpenSSH (yet). It was discussed some time ago on openssh-unix-dev mailing list (thread):

https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2017-May/035992.html

The best chance you have really with Cygwin on Windows or with "native Win32" application made by Windows developers, which "should work" at this moment:

https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Project-Status

Answer (score 2):

[Support for OpenSSH certificates](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/ssh2-openssh-certkeys.html) was added to PuTTY in the current version (v0.78).